# How to make fully filled in Cross star pattern as shown below?

Tags: javascript, java

Please help me in making pattern like this as shown below

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your code attempt here, even you are still stuck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Value of n is the number of rows or the number of stars in first row,it should be odd to get desired pattern

```
public static void show( int n )
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i+=2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = n - i; k > 0; k--) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i+=2) {
        for (int j = n - i; j > 1; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav for your response, but output is not coming as expected. Also what should be the value of "n" ??

Comment: I have made edits and checked the code again,please check it and let me know if it works,sorry for the troubles

Comment: @prashantbalotra `n` is the number of lines, should be `5` for your example.

Comment: yes,it should be 5 and sorry for posting a program without checking i am new as well but trying hard

Comment: Thank you very much  @VaibhavGupta , Now, its working fine.

Comment: Can we solve it by three loops??  with 6 for loops , it's already done.